# how to convert oracle query to db2 query?

Tags: oracle, db2

hi am new to DB2 can anyone please tel me how to convert below oracle query into DB2 query,
`insert into EMPTABLE values((select name from emp),20,'Shankar');`

Answer (score 1):

This query works neither on oracle nor db2. I would try something like:

```
INSERT INTO EmpTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT name, 20, 'Shankar'
FROM Emp
```